# What would make HTML/JS/PHP source suddenly end/stop while loading?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been building a set of mostly HTML and JS functions using Jquery and ajax with PHP backend. For some reason, a page that didn't used to have problems suddenly doesn't load. When I check the document inspector, I find that the code just... stops. Before it ended on a line of HTML. Today, it's in the middle of some JS code (around line 1364).

I had a chunk of JS code commented out that I removed from the code and suddenly it worked... until I brought in some more code from another file and it suddenly stopped again.

What makes HTML code suddenly stop? It's driving me nuts! My code became very fragile.

Comment: You *probably* have a fatal PHP error. Turn on error reporting and then load the page and see what you get.

Comment: Could you actually show code and tell us your debug attempts? We can't you if we don't know the problem/have the code

Comment: John, good point. I gave it a try and didn't notice any errors though :(

Comment: I thought about that Andrew, but what code would I show you? It's over 1800 lines of intermixed PHP, JS, and HTML. I don't know what's making it stop in the middle of code. Even if there was an error in my code, it would still show the code in the inspector. This behavior is very strange.

Comment: John, scratch that, I found an error table in my code in the inspector. I'm going to chase down the various errors.

Answer (score 0):

## Check these ：

1.does JavaScript has syntax error? (check inspector console)
2.does your PHP has syntax or logic error?(Ex:In CentOS 7,type command`#tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`)

## Trouble Shoot

Sometime js do not report error even the program stop.
So, you can add some `console.log('test')` in your code to find out which line cause js exec stop.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove most of my code and reinsert it one section at a time. I found a missing  tag though I still don't understand why the code responded in such a weird way.